# Any concrete information about Ukrainian reforms, necessary for NATO?

Tags: united-states, ukraine, corruption, nato, western-world

There was a NATO summit some days ago, in Brussels. It confirmed a decision towards Ukraine being a NATO member. Article 69 of the joint [Communiqué](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/news_185000.htm?selectedLocale=en) defines specific steps Ukraine has to take in order to get ready for the membership.

For example:

> The success of wide-ranging, sustainable, and irreversible reforms, including combating corruption, promoting an inclusive political process, and decentralisation reform

Sounds very ethereal for me.

**Is there any concrete information about what is meant under "decentralization reform"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hungary [vetoes](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-hungary-nato-ukraine-idUSKBN1X91ZI) any formal contact between NATO and Ukraine until the language rights of minorities are restored to at least the 2014 level. A law then allowed counties to introduce official local languages.

Comment: This post has nothing to do with the original question which asked, "*Is there any concrete information about what is meant under **"decentralization reform"**?*" — your post may benefit from at least pretending to say a word about the decentralization reform. Flagging as non-answer for now.

Comment: It IS answer, just because "establishing territorial communities" as part of "decentralization reform" involves european freedoms. Which are in huge contradiction of today-present oppressing Hungary, Poland and Gagausian minorities in western parts of Ukraine.

Comment: @user2501323, "involves" ≠ "equivalent to". The decentralization, by definition, is when a Hujngarian speaker in a Transcarpathian territorial community pays their taxes for funding a local Hungarian-language school for his very kids (the Ukrainian-language education stays free and state-sponsored). The Hungary, on the contrary, attempts to force Ukraine's central budget sponsor a region's extra expenses. Parasiting on the state central budget **is the opposite to the decentralization and self-governance**.

Comment: I don't get it. Those people in western Ukraine are ukrainian citizens, who are ethnic Hungarians. Why then Ukraine don't support their needs, if they want to save their national identity?

Comment: @user2501323 it is far out of the topic of *this* question about the decentralization reform and *this*, supposedly, "answer" about the Hungarian "veto". You may want to ask it a separate question hoping that someone would answer it for you.

Comment: Still don't get it. Accepted answer directly specifies long-living problem in the specified reform. In fact, some blockade of such reform. Question was "any concrete information about Ukrainian reforms, necessary for NATO". Answer even go deeper - it specifies not only the formalization, but also some context. Which, I'm sure, definitely would be resolved by the Ukrainian government - at least, problem is not looking very principal, isn't it?

Comment: @bytebuster The point is that local communities (before Maidan) had the right to use official local/regional languages besides the country-level official one. Who collects the tax from the taxpayers for such services is I think a secondary matter.

Answer (score 3):

Ukraine has taken the obligation to perform a decentralization reform. The official site [decentralization.gov.ua](https://decentralization.gov.ua/en/about) defines "decentralization" as "Concept of Reforming Local Self-Government and Territorial Structure of Power".

The site says the reform has been inspired by provisions of the **European Charter of Local Self-Government** and the best world practice.

The list of concrete steps is listed in **the Action Plan** and includes:

- amendments to the **Constitution** of Ukraine and developing a package of new legislation;
- amendments to the **Budget** and Tax Codes of Ukraine;
- adopting specific **laws**, including "On Voluntary Amalgamation of Territorial Communities",  "On Cooperation of Territorial Communities", "On Fundamental Principles of the State Regional Policy";
- forming a capable basic level of **local self-government**;
- establishing **territorial communities**.

The effort has been appreciated by the [Venice Commission](https://www.venice.coe.int/), an integral part of the Council of Europe.